# How to get the last item in group by in query builder if not the integer or date?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to get the last row using groupby,
I have some duplicate jobseeker_id but difference call_reason,status,type_of_call, etc. ..and created_at.

```html
id jobseeker_id  type_of_call   status  call_reason        created_at
1   2001          incoming_call  good   because of track   2017.10.1
2   2001          outgoing call  fair    they called me    2017.11.2
3   2001          outgoing call  bad     something         2017.12.3
4   2002          outgoing call  good     something        2018.11.6
```

So I expected to come out only

```html
id jobseeker_id  type_of_call   status  call_reason        created_at
1   2001         outgoing call  bad      something        2017.12.3
4   2002          outgoing call  good     something        2018.11.6
```

Here is my query

```html
           $jobseekers =DB::table('calllogs')
  ->select(DB::raw("max(created_at),jobseeker_id,call_reason,type_of_call"))
    ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
  ->groupBy('jobseeker_id')  
  ->wherenotnull('call_back_date')
  ->get();
```

the above query return me like

```html
id jobseeker_id  type_of_call   status  call_reason        created_at
3   2001          incoming_call  good     because of track         2017.12.3
4   2002          outgoing call  good     something        2018.11.6
```

I can only get the lastest created_at date but i coun't get the latest staus,type_of_call,call_reason.Can anyone have idea? please help me out.

Comment: did you check orderBy after groupBy ?

Comment: Yes I did, same man @EtibarRustemzade any idea bro?

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with laravel but your problem is that you need to identify the row with the id and then select the columns from it. You are trying to get the max created_at and then just getting grouped values for rest of the columns. The query will look something like..

```
SELECT * FROM calllogs WHERE id IN (
(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM calllogs GROUP BY jobseeker_id);
```

I am assuming that the id in the expected results you have shown should be 3 and not 1. The query should work at least for the limited set I can see. Might need to add some more refinements based on rest of your data but this should give you an idea on what might work. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah @clinomaniac, i will try to convert it, thanks for the idea man.

Answer (score 0):

```
$jobseekers =DB::table('calllogs')
  ->select(DB::raw("max(created_at),jobseeker_id,call_reason,type_of_call"))
  ->orderBy('jobseeker_id','desc')
  ->wherenotnull('call_back_date')
  ->take(2)
  ->get();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to clarify why you think your code solves the problem.

Comment: hay bro @Hashan actually, i just showing above the example data, we can't do the static to skip and take 2